# Mongo script to update child array based on condition of array element

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I have been trying for several days to write a script to update the children of a collection based on a value of that array items element. Here is the data structure:

```
{
    "_id" : BinData(3, "nmtYgz4fOkSqXEBp56fPWA=="),
    "FormDefinitionId" : BinData(3, "VTvO8CWP2USuxTQgQ4phYw=="),
    "TemplateFileName" : "mmif_c99999_c999999_2018q3.xlsx",
    "Children" : [
        {
            "DisplayName" : "1 Register",
            "FriendlyName" : "Tab1Register",
            "ElementType" : NumberInt(0),
            "Type" : NumberInt(0),
            "StartRow" : NumberInt(7),
            "SheetName" : "1 Register",           
            "SheetPassword" : "AAA"
        },
        {
            "DisplayName" : "2 Register",
            "FriendlyName" : "Tab2Register",
            "ElementType" : NumberInt(0),
            "Type" : NumberInt(0),
            "StartRow" : NumberInt(7),
            "SheetName" : "2 Register",          
            "SheetPassword" : "AAA"
        },
    ],
    "WorkbookPassword" : "FFFFFFFF&"
}
```

What I need to do is update the Sheet Password to "123" items with a SheetName of "2 Register" only.
This is what I have tried:

```
db.mappingExcel.bulkWrite([
  { "updateMany": {
    "filter": { "FormDefinitionId": { "$eq": BinData(3, "VTvO8CWP2USuxTQgQ4phYw==") } },
    "update": { "$set": { "WorkbookPassword": "AAAAABABABB&" } }
  }},
  { "updateMany": {
    "filter": { "FormDefinitionId": BinData(3, "VTvO8CWP2USuxTQgQ4phYw=="), "Children.SheetName" : "2 Register" },
    "update": { "$set": { "Children.$[].SheetPassword": "123" } }
  }},
  { "updateMany": {
    "filter": { "FormDefinitionId": { "$eq": BinData(3, "VTvO8CWP2USuxTQgQ4phYw==") } },
    "update": { "$set": { "Children.$[].SheetPassword": "123" } },
    "arrayFilters": [{ "Children.$[].SheetName": {$ne : "2 Register"} }]
  }}
])
```

Don't worry about the first updateMany. It does what it is supposed to do. The 2nd UpdateMany updates all the children and the 3rd updates none of them.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using `"arrayFilters"`?

Comment: Yes. As per the last "updateMany"

Comment: Ah, yeah.  Sorry I missed that.  You've got the right idea.  How does this work? `"update": { "$set": { "Children.$[elem].SheetPassword": "123" } },"arrayFilters": [{ "elem.SheetName": "2 Register"}]`

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/AXA3GmfF24S